# How to deal with OPs asking question, receiving lots of high quality answers on which clearly much time was spent and don't thank contributers at all?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, reputation

I have experienced this phenomena now twice in a row.

Somebody asks a question, which sometimes is even ambiguous in terms of emphasis on what of the things they had asked/mentioned need answering and they receive multiple questions basically coded to completion.

Weeks pass and the OPs never return, or return and just leech off the answers without as much as leaving a thank you comment.

I have been actively trying to answer a few questions lately and even went so far to code the whole thing out in a GitHub repo.

To my shame I must admit I was trying to get at least one more reputation point, since I am stuck on 199 for what feels months now.

Comment: We thank contributors by upvoting their posts. "Thank you" comments are just noise. They usually get deleted if you flag them as "too chatty".

Comment: There is nothing you can do I'm afraid. Upvotes come from the community however not just the OP so if you deliver high quality answers the community would be so inclined to upvote them. I often go weeks without so much as a rep increase and there is even a badge, _unsung hero_ I believe it's called, which is awarded for answering but not getting any feedback in terms of votes.

Comment: Also some users don't actually know that the feature of upvoting/accepting answers exists, especially if they are new. Furthermore I've had answers accepted weeks after providing them. Point them to this question; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: This is just part of what happens with the format of the site.  You'll have some questions where you think that you provided the *perfect* answer, and it never gets accepted or up voted, and then you'll have that one answer that you aren't even sure you want to post that gets upvotes months or years later.  The way I look at it, the value of providing answers on the site is less about the points you get from it and more about *you* learning something from providing the answer, or just the satisfaction of knowing you are there to offer your help.

Comment: From a quick look at your most recent answers they were for people with reputation of 1,1, and 6. They won't have reputation to upvote your answers even if they wanted to.

Comment: And most of those questions are pretty dubious quality with close votes on them. If you want to spend a lot of time on an answer you're probably best off focusing on ones with a few upvotes - which is an indication that at least some people in the community feel they are worth answering.

Comment: Good questions to answer in your tag: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20is%3aq%20closed%3ano%20answers%3a0

Comment: Answer for **everyone else**. Your answer should be helpful not just to the asker, but for every future visitor with the same problem. **That** is where the upvotes come from.

Comment: I am in some agreement with this problem. I will cheerfully take a poster to task if they received a great answer but did not respond at all. Whilst we generally discourage "thanks" comments on their own, the OP does not need to be a genius to respond with something more substantial that, as an aside, acknowledges a substantial effort.

Comment: One approach you could have is to only answer substantial, thoughtful questions, perhaps only from established users (200+?). I would hope that not everyone will do that, but unfortunately dump-and-run questions from 1-rep users is commonplace.

Comment: @halfer Of course you don't need to be a genius to respond.  However it's simply not important or necessary that the question author respond.  If they have some feedback that they really want to give, then that's fine, if they don't *then that's also fine*.  It's berating the OP for not responding, when they have no obligation to, that is actually the problematic behavior.

Comment: "which sometimes is even ambiguous in terms of emphasis on what of the things they had asked/mentioned need answering" Funny, how people who can't be bothered to ask a well formatted, clear, concise question can't be bothered to upvote and mark answers correct...

Comment: @Servy: I am not sure if I agree entirely. There is something of an internet "culture of free" that is emerging on Stack Overflow, in the form of help vampirism and do-my-homework-for-me, etc. I think Stack Overflow is not a bad platform to push back on that a bit. We are already training people not to regard the site as a platform for ordering free work (by closing their Q or DVing) - an expectation from some folks that they reply, vote or accept is merely an extension of that.

Comment: I'm not saying folks have to respond to everything, but if they have a long history of dump-and-run, I will sometimes say something. If that gets no response either, I will downvote and explain why.

Comment: @halfer If people are asking *bad questions*, then by all means push back on that.  People asking bad questions is a problem *regardless of whether or not they give feedback on answers*.  If people are asking *good* questions, then we don't care at all if they respond to the answers.  `an expectation from some folks that they reply, vote or accept is merely an extension of that`  It's an unwarranted one.  It's important for people asking questions to ask a good question; it's not important in the slightest for them to give feedback if they don't want to give feedback, in fact, it's *harmful*.

Comment: @halfer If people are not responding to requests for clarification to the question, and the question really needs the clarification, then yes *that* is a problem.  That has nothing whatsoever to do with them giving feedback to answers.  If people are asking unclear questions and not clarifying them, then by all means, downvote and vote to close as unclear.  If they ask a perfectly clear question, and get a perfectly clear answer, they don't need to respond at all.

Comment: I understand your perspective, @Servy, and I expect it is probably the broad view on Meta as well. However, I don't enthusiastically share it, as I think vampirism needs some opposition.

Comment: @halfer **It's not vampirism**.  Vampirism is people *providing bad content*, not people providing *good* content.  Punishing people providing *valuable* content just because they're providing *less* valuable content than you want them to is actively harmful, as you'll make them stop posting more *helpful* content.  Punishing people that are providing *harmful* content, to stop them from posting *more* harmful content, is actually helpful, because we don't' want harmful content.

Comment: By just glancing at some comments - no time doing some home office and I don't like to do private stuff on the side but I couldn't withstand after seeing I had 8(!) new items in my Inbox-  and the fact my question was downvoted to the deepest abyss of SO I must have rained on so many peoples parades which I am sorry for. I will make sure to return later to read through everything properly and reply with a comment that deserves the amount of effort put into commenting/answering on my poor (? - judging by is rating) question. [Speaking of no rep for weeks](http://imgur.com/gallery/BfFWK)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do nothing.

If someone asks a great question, and then doesn't do anything else, then you can upvote the question, if you feel it's a good question.  There is no requirement at all for them to give feedback on answers.  They can if they want, or they can choose not to; either is fine.

Of course if the question is somehow problematic, incomplete, or otherwise in need of improvement, then the OP is expected to be the one to respond to feedback, requests for clarification, and to make any other improvements necessary for the question to be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I read through all the comments to my question including the sole answer and made short notes, a sort of quintessence to help me adjust my mindset regarding my approach for answering questions going forward.

I do agree that answers should be for the benefit of the SO community and all future readers with a similar issue.

#### Lessons learned

After some introspection as to my motives for contributing at all I found a number of drivers. First I enjoy the pure act of writing code that others can apply to their issue either as a pointer in the right direction or in some (rare) cases as the whole solution for that particular part of their problem domain. This comes with the joy of possibly having to acquire more knowledge and in the process overcome challenges, which in itself provides gratification. Upvotes and marked as the accepted answer on my own solution would serve as multiplicators of my gratification and serve my ego alone, which is not very productive.

Therefore going forward I will approach the process of creating solutions that maximize the benefit of others and where possible mine as well if it is of the kind that allows me to gain more knowledge and experience but expressly not one for serving my ego and my ego alone.

Once having provided such a solution I will not expect any feedback from the OP that is to the sole effect of expressing his gratitude. I will be prepared to adapt my solution if prompted so by the OP, third parties, external circumstances or my own realization of oversights, shortcomings, errors or any other element in my solution that is to its detriment. I will enjoy upvotes on my solution or even the fact that it was marked as the accepted answer should it so happen and treat it as indication of its benefit to others and again expressly not as means to serve my ego.

This is my solution to the question I asked and probably has little benefit to others since its a result of introspection combined with the comments to my question as well as the answer from Servy.

#### Further things to consider

But above described adjustment of my approach to answering questions does not cover the full extent of things I have taken away from this. There were other good points made that could help in the future.

For example trying to pick questions that have already received some upvotes as an indication the community has a vested interest in receiving an optimal solution is definitely good advice.

Avoiding questions of dubious quality from users with low reputation I find a very good tip on how to decide if I should invest time in finding a solution under these circumstances. Should I still find myself providing an answer to a question under above mentioned circumstances, I have made note of a historic question asked on SO mentioned in one of the comments which was migrated to Meta asking *[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)* and which I think might be worth pinning under a solution in such cases.

So is to pick questions from users the are at a similar reputation level as me but preferably above indicating implicitly a higher quality of question. I have to admit though that I have actively shied away from trying to answer such questions always feeling not being qualified enough or being sufficiently deficient in my intelligence as reasons.

I am sure that is true for an undetermined amount of those questions but there are certainly some especially in areas where that kind of technology is part of the problem that I use regularly in my day job, which are `C#.NET`, `Entity Framework`, `ASP.NET MVC/WebForms`, `JavaScript`, `jQuery`, `Kendo UI MVC`, asf.